# Redirection of cakephp pages to a different url if the entered url is not found

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to redirect to a different url if the entered url is not found.
Url's and corresponding routes are given below.

Here if i enter the second url in the browser it should redirect to the first url.How can i achive this.

```
Url:
http://domain.com/users/username/news

Route:
Router::connect('/users/:sluguser/:action', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'news'),array('pass' => array('sluguser')));

Url:
http://domain.com/users/username

Route:
Router::redirect('/users/:sluguser', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'news'),array('pass' => array('sluguser'),'status'=>'301'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class AppError extends ErrorHandler {
    function missingAction($parameters) {
        $this->controller->redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Pls read http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#using-appcontroller-apperror

Comment: Here i am not getting any missing error, the two url's should execute the same action.

Comment: Pls elaborate your question.